# select specific rows with class names

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an HTML which has bunch of rows that I want to select. Here are example of those rows

```
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue1-row" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue1-row'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue1-row" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue1-row'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
```

What i was trying to do is use `BeautifulSoup4` and `find_all` using a regex `find_all(re.compile(regext))`

However, the problem is that i am unable to come up with a good regext which will select all rows that i am interested in.

all the rows that i want start with `constantstring-`. I don't care what it is followed by. What would be the proper way, should i use `re.compile` and if so, what will be the correct `regex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this with RE the following will do, I added an extra row to demo it not picking up the final row.

http://rextester.com/OSSFB8621

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html ="""
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue1-row" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue1-row'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue1-row" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue1-row'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
<tr class="axcconstantstring-randomvalue2-row-2" onmouseover="this.className='constantstring-light-row-cp-h'" onmouseout="this.className='constantstring-randomvalue2-row-2'" onclick="if(ignoreOnClick==false)window.location='find.ashx?cv3dsw'" valign="top">
"""
bs = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
for tr in bs.find_all("tr", {"class" : re.compile('^(constantstring)')}):
    print(tr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you can use in-built string methods for the same task. Like,

```
rows = soup.find_all('tr)'
selected_rows = [i for i in rows if str(i).startswith('tr class="constantstring-randomvalue')]
```

If you miss `str()` the `if` condition will fail.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: i am not good at python so perhaps you can explain a bit more the last line. the `class` is not `constantstring`. it will start with `constantstring` but it can have subsequent letters i.e., `<tr class="constantstring-randvalue-op1" onmous ... >`

Comment: i have changed the code so that you can easily understand. `find_all` will make a list of all `tr`elements from your web page. The second line is a list comprehension which iterates through the list and stores the values which starts with `tr class="constantstring-randomvalue`.